# Azure Data Transfer for High Frequency / Small Size

Tags: azure, rest, azure-data-factory

I am looking at an Azure Architecture for a client.

Requirement: Client runs a call centre. Their call centre management software tools are on-prem. The databases (MSSQL,MySQL,FileBased) for their software is also on-prem. They would like to transfer the call data and client interaction data from on-prem to Azure SQL DB. Now this Azure SQL DB will be designed as an Operational Data Store so once the data has landed in staging tables, a SQL Stored Procedure will be run to process the data to datamart tables.

The data in the ODS datamart tables will be used in PowerBI that is displayed in their call centres on large screens indicating up-to-date stats like number of calls made, target calls for the day, number of leads, ring time etc.

[image]

Now they require a rather high frequency of data transfer to happen. Ranging from every 30seconds for  call data or every 5 minutes for leads data. But the amount of data will range from 10-100 records per transfer. The reason for this is because they want near-realtime dashboards displayed.

Now having looked at Azure Data Factory, I found that using it for near realtime data transfering can become very expensive. A single copy data pipeline can cost them around $3200 per month. And there wil be several of these pipelines. This is not possible with the client's budget for opertional cost. :(

**I need suggestions for an alternative approach**.

Where small batches of data can be transered to Azure SQL Database at high frequency from on-prem datasources.

What I have considered thus far is developing an on-prem Windows Service (with .Net) that push data to Azure SQL, but this will take alot of development and require after sales support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after removing my head from my backside, i realised that the biggest issue was in the calculation of the cost.

[image]

So after watching some very insightfull videos ([Understanding Azure Data Factory Pricing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c958SwJ8lpg)) I figured out how to determine the value of the variables used in the azure pricing calculator.

So it brought the monthly bill down to about $50.